# Pop-up window not fully visible

Tags: display, display-manager

I am unable to view full popup window while opening the security option in Acrobat preference section.

Attached screenshot for reference. How can I fix this

My screen resolution is 3840*2160

[image: Acrobat--> View --> Preference --> Security]

Comment: What version Ubuntu?

Comment: @heynnema I am using Ubuntu 18.04 version

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for edits.

Comment: Have you either, 1) installed a custom theme, 2) installed some custom fonts, or more likely 3) used scaling in the Ubuntu `Displays` settings panel?